# Git help - proper directory

Tags: git

I need some enlightenment here .

$which git
/usr/bin/git

-- so the problem is it is not on the right directory ..

how do I change its path or make it to the right one

/usr/local/bin/git

---- can somebody help me with this

Comment: `/usr/bin/git` is correct though. Why do you want `/usr/local/bin/git`?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct path .. I am searching for answers on this one ..

Comment: I read something like this  The easiest way to check for Git is to start a terminal window and use which6 at the command line to see if the git executable is already present:
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

Comment: which doesnt make sense .. do I need to remove git and reinstall it and what is the right way of installing it step by step on the terminal

Comment: What's the exact error you get when you try to run git ?   are you trying to `git clone` or `git pull`  ? Explain exactly what you're doing

Comment: No I am just playing around with git and Im not sure this is the right path to be in. or should it be in /usr/local/bin

Comment: Copy directly doesn't work for you?

Comment: im not sure how to do it can you show me step by step